# How to delete all images with a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have created a button that adds an image to certain cells of the table:

```
function numeruoti(){
            for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
                document.getElementById("data"+i).innerHTML="<img src='JPEG/" +i+ ".png'>" + document.getElementById("data"+i).innerHTML;
        }
    }
```

Now i need to create a button that deletes all of the images that have been added (but leaves information on those cells that was before adding images).

Here i'm trying something, but i'm new to JS..:

```
 function naikinti(){
    document.getElementByTagName('img').innerHTML = 'none';
    }
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Open your developer console to view error messages, and since you're new to JS, consider running through some beginner tutorials on JavaScript and DOM manipulation. [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been searching, but probably badly. Sorry for a duplicate.

Comment: in your naikinti function: instead of setting `innerHTML='none'`, try set it to an empty string instead: `innerHTML=''`. Also what are you getting right now with this code?

Comment: `img` tags don't have inner html. `<img src='google.png' />` No inner html there.